# Laravel 5 create simple Route and using model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i'm new in laravel 5 and i'm trying to create simple route and using model,

my simple route is:

```
Route::get('/register_by_mobile', array(
    'as' => 'register_by_mobile', function () {
        $data                = new VerifyMobiles();
        $data->mobile_number = Input::get('phone_number');
        $data->valid_code    = 123;
        $data->save();
));
```

`laravel-root\app\VerifyMobiles.php` contains:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VerifyMobiles extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'verify_mobiles';
}
```

now in firefox address bar i'm try to request this url:

```
http://localhost/laravel5/register_by_mobile?phone_number=111
```

i get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in routes.php : 
    Class 'VerifyMobiles' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is namespaced

```
namespace App;
```

Try changing the route to

```
$data                = new \App\VerifyMobiles();
```

Comment: thanks sir. after create Model directory in App, how to change namespace and $data ?

Comment: If you put your models in app/Models, just change the namespace in the model from namespace App; to namespace App/Models;

Instantiate the class like $data = new \App\Models\VerifyMobiles()